# Linked List Sorting Using Bubble Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I'm Trying to sort a link list using bubble sort.But the algorithm i wrote doesn't work.Can anybody help me???

there is a link class also.

Link class

```
public class Link {
    public int iData;
    public String sData;
    public Link next;

    public Link(int id,String sd)
    {
    iData =id;
    sData =sd;
    next = null;
    }
    public void displayLink()
    {
    System.out.println(iData+""+sData); 
    }
    }
```

LinkKist class including sorting algorithm.

```
public class LinkedList {

    private Link first;

    public void LinkList() {

        first = null;

    }

  public void insertFirst(int idata, String sdata) {
        Link nl1 = new Link(idata, sdata);

        nl1.next = first;
        first = nl1;
    }

public void displayList() {
    System.out.println("List : ");
    Link current = first;
    while (current != null) {
        current.displayLink();
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

    public void sortll(){


        Link current = first;
        Link nextLink = first.next;

        while(current.next != null){

            while(nextLink.next != null)

            if(nextLink.iData < current.iData){

                Link temp = nextLink;
                nextLink = current;
                current = temp;

                nextLink = nextLink.next;
                current = current.next;

            }

        current = current.next;
        }


    }
}
```

test app.

```
public class LLtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList ll1 = new LinkedList();

        ll1.insertFirst(11, "UWU0011");
        ll1.insertFirst(3, "UWU0003");
        ll1.insertFirst(1, "UWU0001");
        ll1.insertFirst(4, "UWU0004");
        ll1.insertFirst(5, "UWU0005");
        ll1.insertFirst(6, "UWU0006");
        ll1.insertFirst(7, "UWU0007");
        ll1.insertFirst(10, "UWU0010");
        ll1.insertFirst(9, "UWU0009");
        ll1.insertFirst(2, "UWU0002");
        ll1.insertFirst(8, "UWU0008");



        ll1.sortll();


        ll1.displayList();
    }
}
```

can anyone please help me?????

Comment: Here's a useful link on how to debug small programs: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: can you help me to solve this????

Comment: What sort of help are you expecting that isn't just someone else debugging your code for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the above problem.

```
public class LinkedList {

        private Link first;

        public void LinkList() {

            first = null;

        }

    public void sortingLinkList(){   //working 

        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            flag = false;

            Link position = first;
            Link positionNext = position.next;
            Link positionPrev = null;

            while (positionNext != null) {
                if(position.iData > positionNext.iData) {

                    Link temp = position;
                    Link tempNextNext = positionNext.next;
                    position = positionNext;
                    position.next = temp;
                    positionNext = temp;
                    positionNext.next = tempNextNext;

                    if (positionPrev == null) { // position is head
                        first = position;
                    } else {
                        positionPrev.next = position;
                    }

                    flag = true;
                }
                positionPrev = position;
                position = position.next;
                positionNext = position.next;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your sorting algo, i feel you are not doing bubble sort.i added the sortll() method that swaps the linked list data but doesn,t swap the links. i think you are trying swap the links, if you are doing that then you need to be more careful in swapping links as you need to consider the end cases carefully. replace the sortll() method and check it

```
public void sortll(){


    Link current = first;
     System.out.println(first.iData);
    Link nextLink = first.next;
    /*while(current.next != null){

        while(nextLink.next != null)

        if(nextLink.iData < current.iData){

            Link temp = nextLink;
            nextLink = current;
            current = temp;

            nextLink = nextLink.next;
            current = current.next;

        }

    current = current.next;
    }*/
    int length=0;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        length++;
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println(length);

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
         Link temp=first;
        for(int j=0;j<length-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(temp.iData>temp.next.iData)
            {
                int tempiData = temp.iData;
                String tempsData =temp.sData;
                temp.iData =temp.next.iData;
                temp.sData =temp.next.sData;
                temp.next.iData=tempiData;
                temp.next.sData=tempsData;
            }
            temp=temp.next;
        }
    }


}
}
```